# Angular 7: Clear selection with x-button on a dropdown box

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I thought I can combine the examples from Angular for [dropdown](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples) and the [Input with clear box](https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples) to:

```
<mat-form-field >
  <mat-select placeholder="Country" [(value)]="selectedCountry" (selectionChange)="emitItemChanges()">
    <div *ngFor="let item of lstItems|async">
      <mat-option *ngIf="addItem(item)" [value]="item">{{item.title}}</mat-option>
    </div>
  </mat-select>
  <button mat-button *ngIf="selectedCountry" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" 
    (click)="selectedCountry=undefined">
    <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-form-field>
```

Which works close to the way as intended

[image]

which clears the input. The problem I'm facing now is that it immediately opens the selection box. Anyway how to prevent this behaviour?

I know there exists other solutions for clearing the selection. I want to know if this approach is possible?

Comment: `(click)="selectedCountry=undefined; $event.preventDefault()">`

Comment: No, this doesn't help :-( It seems like the event is nevertheless handled. But ... see updated answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`(click)="selectedCountry=undefined; $event.stopPropagation()"` helped! Thx to @Sachila :-)

So the full code looks like:

```
  <button mat-button *ngIf="selectedCountry" matSuffix mat-icon-button 
    aria-label="Clear" (click)="selectedCountry=undefined; $event.stopPropagation()">
  <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
  </button>
```

Comment: (click)="searchForm.get('to').setValue(''); $event.stopPropagation()"

this worked for me. I only had (click)="searchForm.get('to').setValue('') but then I was not getting the  dropdown added stopPropagation and it started working

Answer (score 6):

**Example for Reactive Forms**

`$event.stopPropagation()` - doesn't open select again

```
       <mat-form-field>
         <mat-select formControlName="team" placeholder="Team">
           <mat-option *ngFor="let team of availableTeams" [value]="team.id">{{team.name}}</mat-option>
         </mat-select>
         <button *ngIf="form.controls.team.value"
                 matSuffix
                 mat-icon-button
                 type="button"
                 aria-label="Clear"
                 (click)="form.controls.team.setValue(null); $event.stopPropagation()">
           <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
         </button>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: How can this be achieved to deselect multiple mat-selects by using one button to deselect all. Say by using a button click method in component.ts? How to handle the $event.stopPropogation() part? e.g. ```onClearFilters() {  
 ... setValues of all mat-selects to null;   } ```

Comment: I have a similar issue when I select a value from the dropdown after removing and setting the value to empty Im unable to see the dropdown again until I click outside. any solution for that.

<button mat-button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="searchForm.get('to').setValue('')"
                    *ngIf="searchForm.get('to').value && !_loaderTo">
                    <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
                </button>

Comment: Perhaps make a an own question. I would guess you need to run a `ChangeDetction.detectChanges()` after you've removed your item. But honestly I didn't understand very well what you're asking about - in sense of workflow.