# How do I get ngModel of children in parent directive?

Tags: angular

I have created a directive and assigned this to an element, It's children element is a input with ngModel, I want to reset child ngModel from parent directive

**I have tried this**

**HTML**:-

---

```
<div wrapper [childModel]="childElm">
  <input type="text" [ngModel]="name" #childElm>
</div>
```

### **TS**:-

**Wrapper Directive**

```
@Input(childModel) childModel;

someFunc() {
   this.childModel.control.setValue(null);
}
```

Is there any other way, without using @Input. Because In this way I had to create local template variable and assign that to @Input.

Comment: I recommend you to take a look at this: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Isn't be well in this case create component instead of attribute and use ViewChild to access content of the parent element? https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ContentChild or ContentChildren. As you want look for NgModel, your directive becomes like

```
  @ContentChild(NgControl, { static: true }) input

  someFunc() {
    this.input.control.setValue(null);
  }
```

(NgControl) is any input with [ngModel] or a input with [formControl], or formControlName if we are working with ReactiveForm

We can has a app.component like

```
<div  hello >
  <input [ngModel]="value"/>
</div>
<button (click)="do()">clear</button>

export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild(HelloDirective,{static:true}) wrapper
  do()
  {
    this.wrapper.someFunc()
  }
}
```

See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmcmnc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE: really to clean a input it's not necesary create a directive, but I supouse this is a part of something more complex

**Updated** when we want to have a "clear" button in Angular Material, the 4th example of the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples) give as a chance

```
<mat-form-field class="example-form-field">
  <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Clearable input" [(ngModel)]="value">
  <button mat-button *ngIf="value" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="value=''">
    <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-form-field>
```

To see how make functional with a select, see the [stackoverflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53555741/angular-7-clear-selection-with-x-button-on-a-dropdown-box)

But the question is, We can make a directive to acheive some similar? (And the answer is true). But our directive must make use of Renderer2 and -I have not find another way- create a cross by .css.

The .css is like

```
.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: -1rem;
  top: -2.5rem;
  width: .8rem;
  height: .8rem;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.close:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.close:before, .close:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: .4rem;
  content: ' ';
  height: .7rem;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #333;
}
.close:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.close:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

And the directive becomes as (see the comment for a briefly explanation)

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[clear]',
  host: {  //we need an "extra" space to the rigth
    '[style.margin-right]': '"1.5rem"',
  }
})
export class ClearDirective implements OnInit {

  div: any;
  @ContentChild(NgControl) control; //we get the "input"

  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) click($event) {
    //we add a HostListener "click" and take account is we click
    //in the "cross" we created, is a span with class="close"
    if ($event.target.getAttribute('class') == 'close') {
      this.control.control.setValue(null);  //remember, the control is the NgControl
      $event.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    //we need take account about when the value of the control is "something"
    //or none
    if (this.control)
      this.control.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
        if (!value) {  //if no value
          this.clearCross()  //remove the cross
        }
        else {
          if (!this.div) {  //if not yet the cross
            this.createCross()  //create
          }
        }
      })

  }
  createCross() {
    //we wan create some like
    /*
       <div class="mat-form-field-suffix">
         <span class="close"></span>
       </div>
    */
    this.div = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    this.renderer.addClass(this.div, "mat-form-field-suffix")

    const span = this.renderer.createElement('span')
    this.renderer.addClass(span, "close")

    this.renderer.appendChild(this.div, span);
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, this.div);
  }
  clearCross() {
    if (this.div)  //simply remove the "cross"
    {
      this.renderer.removeChild(this.el.nativeElement, this.div)
      this.div=null
    }
  }
```

You can use like, e.g.

```
<mat-form-field clear>
  <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Clearable input" [(ngModel)]="value">
</mat-form-field>
```

Well, the full example (based in a forked stackblitz of @SammerKant) is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sameer-material-select-filter-xytczc?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.html)

**Update 2**, well, some I don't like is that the directive goes outside the input. really I don't like it. So, with the same philosophia, change a bit the css to adjust the position, the new directive is in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sameer-material-select-filter-mvnqnk?file=app%2Fclear.directive.ts)

```
export class ClearDirective implements OnInit {

  div: any;
  constructor(@Optional() private control:NgControl,private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.control)
      this.control.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
        if (!value) {
          this.clearCross()
        }
        else {
          if (!this.div) {
            this.createCross()
          }
        }
      })

  }
  createCross() {
    this.div = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    this.renderer.addClass(this.div, "wrapper")

    const span = this.renderer.createElement('span')
    this.renderer.addClass(span, "close")

    this.renderer.appendChild(this.div, span);
    this.renderer.insertBefore(this.renderer.parentNode(this.el.nativeElement),this.div,this.el.nativeElement,);
    this.renderer.listen(this.div, 'click', ($event) => {
           this.control.control.setValue(null);
           $event.stopPropagation();
       });
  }
  clearCross() {
    if (this.div)
    {
      this.renderer.removeChild(this.renderer.parentNode(this.el.nativeElement), this.div)
      this.div=null
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an `Output` property with the name `childModelChange()`. Then Angular will automatically update the parent property. Then we need to `emit()` an event whenever the child changes the value:

You could set up event emitter communication (outputs) from child to parent. For example like this:

import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output} from 'angular2/core'

```
@Component({
    selector: 'yourChild',
    template: `
        <p>yourChild yourSharedVariable: {{yourSharedVariable}}</p>
        <input [ngModel]="yourSharedVariable" (ngModelChange)="change($event)">
    `
})
export class yourChildComponent {
    @Input() yourSharedVariable: string;
    @Output() yourSharedVariableChange = new EventEmitter();
    change(newValue) {
      console.log('newvalue', newValue)
      this.yourSharedVariable = newValue;
      this.yourSharedVariableChange.emit(newValue);
    }
}
```

Your parent component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: `
        <div>Parent yourSharedVariableParent: {{yourSharedVariableParent}}</div>
        <yourChild [(yourSharedVariable)]="yourSharedVariableParent"></yourChild>
    `,
    directives: [yourChildComponent]
})
export class ParentComponent {
    yourSharedVariableParent ='hello';
    constructor() { console.clear(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all for your response,

This works using `@ContentChildren`, Because `@ContentChild` always gives first/parent ngModel, But I Need a Specific ngModel so I used `@ContentChildren`

Like

```
@ContentChildren(NgControl) input;
this.input.last.control.setValue(null);
```

Currently In my case there wil be only one child, so for time being I am accessing as `this.input.last.control.setValue(null);`
What if there are multiple ngModels and from that How can I get specific ngModel

By the way, I have created a search for Material Select [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sameer-material-select-filter?file=app%2Fmaterial-filter.directive.ts), On Open I am focusing input field(Search Box) and On Close Clearing its ngModel

Note: I Don't want to create a component as this increase lots of code and logics

Comment: @Sammer Khan, I updated my answer, I don`t know if this can help you

Comment: @Eliseo, I think I haven't explain my question clearly, Sorry about that.
I am creating select with search [Something Like This] (https://cuppalabs.github.io/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/#/searchfilter) 
OnClosing select input it clears search keyword, not with addition button

Comment: A new Update :)